# Can't figure out my syntax error in Octave script

Tags: matlab, syntax-error, octave

I don't understand why this error is coming up and I've been frying my brain but can't find it. The error reads: `subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals` called from line 51 column 12, I'll mark it in the code below.

I don't see why my code is interpreting that I'm using `xintv4` as a subscript. `f2` is a function and I'm calling it to evaluate a set of x-values...

```
f2 =@(x) x.^2 .* e.^(-x).*sin(pi.*x);

a4 = -1;
    b4 = 1;
    c4 = 0.84685; 

    for N4 = [10]#, 100, 1000, 10000]

      disp("");

      B = 1;            

      for p4 = 1:2

        xintv4 = rand(1,N4)*2-1;
        yintv4 = rand(1,N4)+c4;
        f2 = f2(xintv4)+c4; #error points to this line at the "=" sign
        nf4 = 0;
        nf4count = 0;   
        nf4 = f2./yintv4;          

        for k = 1:N4

                if nf4(k) >= 1

                  nf4count += 1;

                else

                  nf4count += 0;

                end                   

        endfor

        #disp("nf:");disp(nf);
        #disp("nfcount:");disp(nfcount);

        I4(p4) = ((B+c4)*(b4-a4)*(nf4count/N4))-(c4*(b4-a4));           

      endfor

      meanI4 = mean(I4);
      stdevI4 = std(I4);

      disp("N = "); disp(N4);
      disp("Mean of the integral using method 2:");disp(meanI4); 
      disp("Standard deviation of the integral using method 2:");disp(stdevI4);       

    endfor
```

I tried playing around with the `for p4 = 1:2` by changing it to `for p4 = 1` and this worked, but I breaks when I increase the loop to 2,3 or 4 (etc).

Added the MATLAB tag because they are similar languages.

Comment: Minimal debugging method: test `f2(xintv4)` after the error, then just `f2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f2 = f2(xintv4)+c4;
```

You assign the return value of the anonymous function `f2` to the **variable** `f2`. The second time around, `f2` is no longer a function name.